# What is the difference between `constant_score + filter` and `term` query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two queries in `Elasticsearch`:

```
{
    "term" : {
        "price" : 20
    }
}
```

and

```
"constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "price" : 20
                }
            }
        }
```

They are returning the same query result. I wonder what the main difference between them. I read some articles about `scoring` document. And I believe both queries are scoring document. The `constant_score` will use `default score 1.0` to match the document's score. So I don't see much difference between these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results would be exactly the exact.

However, the biggest difference is that the `constant_score/filter` version will cache the results of the `term` query since it's run in a [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html). All future executions will leverage that cache. Also, one feature of the `constant_score` query is that the returned score is always equal to the given boost value (which defaults to 1)

The first query will be run outside of the filter context and hence not benefit from the filter cache.

Comment: I agree with you on that the filter context will cache the result. But in terms of `constant_score`, since I am using `term` query, the score should be always 1 in `term` query right? So in this case, there is no different for scoring. Is it correct?

Comment: There's no difference in scoring. A term query will always return 1, since it's basically a yes/no filter, same a a constant_score query with a boost of 1. The only difference here is in the performance, constant_score will leverage the filter cache, while the single term query will not